# Как сортировать элементы в разных списках одновременно?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript, sortable

У меня есть 4 блока, нижний блок, откуда я беру элементы, 3 верхних, куда я из могу размещать.

Первый блок (совместный): когда я перемещаю элемент сюда, он клонируется в 2 нижних блока.
Второй и третий блоки: когда я бросаю элемент на них, он просто становиться туда.

Я нашёл вариант решения проблемы, со свойством absolute.
Но работает очень криво, вернее верхние сортируются, а нижние гдето зависают.

**Прошу помощи.

Собственно, вот код: http://jsfiddle.net/54j53cnh/**

Скрин:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Вот как раз если убрать свойство `position: "absolute"` , то ничего нигде не зависает из нижних 2-х блоков. Другой вопрос - конечная цель какая? Не очень понятна задача, вы описали некий алгоритм, а как он должен корректно выполняться - не ясно. Поясните ваши цели.